# expressjs-similar Framework in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, express, frameworks

Is outside there an expressjs similar framework for Java?
I'm looking for an small framework which can process different HTTP-Requests and send response, cookies etc. As in expressjs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I decided to roll out my own framework. It's called [java-express](https://github.com/Simonwep/java-express). The API is very similar to the one of expressjs:

```
Express app  = new Express();

app.get("/", (req, res) -> {
    res.send("Hello World");
});

app.listen();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to something more "production-ready", you definitely want to take a look at [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

This tutorial is simple, but very useful for you to begin: ["Building a RESTful Web Service"](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

If you like to use "untyped" variables, Groovy language can come to your help. 100% compatible with Java. There is even another frameworks called [Grails](https://grails.org/) that use groovy as main language. You may also take a look on that too.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [Javalin](https://javalin.io), it's minimal and lightweight like Express but the API is more similar to [qua](https://koajs.com/), they say it's is more of a library than a framework, No DI or annotations, here's a hello world example:

```
import io.javalin.Javalin;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Javalin app = Javalin.create().start(7000);
        app.get("/", ctx -> ctx.result("Hello World"));
    }
}
```